# which Questions to ask on which StackExchange website

Tags: discussion, support, questions

Finally i have found a place where can i put my query.I have been actively involved with StackOverflow for 8 months as [**Algorithmist**](https://stackoverflow.com/users/462445/algorithmist). But every now and then I find that most naive users (including me) are afraid to ask a question.

The reason being that if you ask some question which is not meant for that particular community then you see a blue banner below your post saying **closed as not a real question by** XXX ,YYY users.

So for the sake of convenience of other naive users like me, can the maestros, genius and expert users of the StackExchange can post their insights of where to post which type of questions.

It would be better if you include the site along with the type of questions that we can ask over there.

Comment: Have you looked over the FAQs for each site (click on the `faq` link next to the search box).  That should give you a general idea.  If your question is more nuanced, what is the specific topic?

Answer (score 9):

**not a real question** isn't about being on the wrong site, it means the question was just poorly asked. Either people couldn't understand what was being asked (maybe the user forgot to identify what *was* happening and how it differed from what they *wanted* to happen), or it was an opinion question, or something else that doesn't fit the Q&A format, or it was a "give me teh codez" question that showed no effort on the part of the asker.

For picking the right site, I'd think 8 months would be plenty to get a feel for what's on topic. There are some edge cases where you have to take your chances. In those cases, it should get migrated rather than closed, which isn't necessarily a punishment, it's just trying to keep things organized.

For sites that you're new to, read the FAQs and just browse a little and see which one has questions most similar to what you want to ask.

Answer (score 6):

I think **8 months** should have given you a good idea of what questions are acceptable, but I agree, it may not be obvious to a *new* user.

Surely, then, the sensible thing for new users to do is to read other people's questions and answers *and try to absorb what is required and acceptable*

Far too many new users dive in an ask question immediately — I suppose that's why they come there — but time spent learning the ropes **and reading the [FAQ](https://stackoverflow.com/faq) will pay dividends**.

Answer (score 4):

The correct place to look for this information is the FAQ for each site. The first section should define as clearly as possible what kinds of questions are and are not expected to be on topic for that site. For example [StackOverflows FAQ here is here](https://stackoverflow.com/faq).

It is not uncommon to find references to other sites in the FAQ. When there is frequent confusion about certain kinds of questions, the correct site for that question will often be mentioned. Go there and check that sites FAQ for clarification. For example the general [Linux](http://unix.stackexchange.com) vs [Ubuntu](http://ubuntu.stackexchange.com) sites are confusing, but the [Linux site FAQ](https://unix.stackexchange.com/faq) states clearly when to use which.

If it is still unclear after reading the FAQ for a site, you can ask for clarification on that sites meta.

There are a large number of SE sites. You can see the full list including beta sites on the [SE main site directory](https://stackexchange.com/sites). Each includes a one line summary of the general topic, and if you want more details about that site you can click through and look at the FAQ page which will always be listed in the very top menu near the right.

Lastly, don't be afraid to ask questions. If they they are in the wrong place they will get migrated. Just make sure you put some effort yourself into asking [good quality questions](http://tinyurl.com/so-hints).